# Split with multiple delimiters

Tags: vbscript, split

I have a text file that I need to split line by line with two delimiters.

```
'Testing' # Libname
'Testing2' #Libname2
```

But, what I want is:

```
Testing Libname
Testing2 Libname2
```

For the moment my code just puts the following:

```
Testing
Libname
Testing2
Libname2
```

Any ideas?

```
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(WScript.Arguments(0) & "\listofpaths.csv", ForReading)
strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strNewText = Replace(strText, Chr(34), "'") 'Replace Double Quote for Single Quote
strNewText = Replace(strNewText, "'", "#")  'Replace 
CharacterCount = (Len(strNewText) - Len(Replace(strNewText, "#", "")))

Set objNewFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(WScript.Arguments(0) & "\listofpaths.csv", ForWriting, True)
objNewFile.Write strNewText
objNewFile.Close

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(WScript.Arguments(0) & "\listofpaths.csv", ForWriting, True)

For i=1 To CharacterCount
    splitstr = Split(strNewText, "#")
    objFile.WriteLine splitstr(i) '& "#" & splitstr1(i)
    i = i + 1
Next

objFile.Close
WScript.Echo "  Process completed "
```

Comment: To preserve the concept of a line, process your input file line by line instead of using .ReadAll. Read and write at the same time using two files. If you want to use the same file name, you can use fso.MoveFile at the end to rename your temporary output file to the name of the original file. This also has the advantage of taking less RAM.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How you will read line by line and Split correctly the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the simple code which will open the file, read content and close it. And then re-open the file and write replaced content and close it.

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
filename = WScript.Arguments(0) & "\listofpaths.csv"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'READ THE CONTENT
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename, ForReading)
tempTxt = f.ReadAll()
f.Close

'REPLACE AND WRITE THE CONTENT BACK
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename, ForWriting, False)
f.Write Replace(Replace(tempTxt, "'", ""), "#", "")

f.Close
Set f = Nothing : Set fso = Nothing
```

Here is the before text:

> 'Testing' # Libname
>   'Testing2' #Libname2
>   'Testing3' # Libname
>   'Testing' #Libname4

And here is the after text in a same file:

> Testing  Libname
>   Testing2 Libname2
>   Testing3  Libname
>   Testing Libname4

Comment: Exactly what I want, except that the line Replace is not working. I need to Delete everything before the Testing Statements.

Comment: Can you explain which part of my code is not working for you.